# How to get image file name inside a folder with jpeg extension and rename it?

Tags: c#

There is a folder with an image and every month we change the image in the folder with different names. I need to get the image filename and then rename it to a default image filename to be loaded into a picture box automatically once form runs.

string fileName = Path.GetFileName(@"\\192.168.1.100\pic\a.jpeg");
label1.Text = fileName;

I tried this code but the path contains the image name. What if we change the image inside the folder with different name? It will cause error. I need to get automatically the image name with a specific extension, jpeg for example. And then rename it to a.jpeg. Every image pasted to the folder will have a default name which is a.jpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get files with a certain extension using

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpeg");
```

and for renaming you can use

```
System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");
```

Comment: string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\192.168.1.100\\pic", "*.jpeg"); 
foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
            {
                if (fileName.EndsWith(".jpeg"))
                {
                    label1.Text = fileName;
                    string path = label1.Text;
                    System.IO.File.Move(fileName,@"\\192.168.232.100\safe\pic\a.jpeg");
                }
            } I tried this code but it doesn't work

Comment: It says make sure relative path is correct but I have found the solution, just a syntax error. It's working now!